# Como puede cambiar las configuracion del panel de contro de windows desde la cmd como adaptadores de red

Tags: cmd

Necesito cambiar configuraciones de los adaptadores de red

Answer (score 1):

En windows para activar o desactivar los adaptadores de red desde el cmd se puede hacer con el comando netsh, entrando como administrador al cmd:

Para listar los adaptadores de red disponibles:

```
netsh interface show interface
```

Una vez tengas los nombres, para habilitar un adaptador de red de los listados anteriormente, utilizas el siguiente comando, sustituyendo 'Nombre de adaptador de red' por algunos de los nombres que te aparecieron en la lista anteriormente :

```
netsh interface set interface 'Nombre de adaptador de red' admin=enable
```

Para deshabilitar un adaptador de red realizas el mismo procedimiento anterior pero con este comando:

```
netsh interface set interface 'Nombre de adaptador de red' admin=disable
```